# C++ templates and ambiguity problem

Tags: c++, templates, ambiguity, implicit-conversion, ambiguous-call

I have a subset of a pointer class that look like:

```
template <typename T>
struct Pointer
{
     Pointer();
     Pointer(T *const x);
     Pointer(const Pointer &x);
     template <typename t>
     Pointer(const Pointer<t> &x);

     operator T *() const;
};
```

The goal of the last constructor is to allow to pass a `Pointer` of a subclass, or basically any type that is implicitly convertable to `T *`. This actual rule is only enforced by the definition of the constructor and the compiler can't actually figure it out by the declaration alone. If I drop it, and try to pass a `Pointer<Sub>` to a constructor of `Pointer<Base>`, I get a compile error, despite of the possible path through `operator T *()`.

While it solves the above problem, it creates another one. If I have an overloaded function whose one overload takes a `Pointer<UnrelatedClass>` and the other takes `Pointer<BaseClass>`, and I try to invoke it with a `Pointer<SubClass>`, I get an ambiguity between the two overloads, with the intention, ofcourse, that the latter overload will be called.

Any suggestions? (Hopefully I was clear enough)

Comment: It's much more common to use a capital `U` as additional template arguments. A lower-case `t` almost looks like a typo.

Comment: Implicit conversion is a bad idea. Use `T * get()` instead of `operator T*()`. shared_ptr does something like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cure for your problem is called SFINAE (substitution failure is not an error)

```
#include "boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp"
#include "boost/utility/enable_if.hpp"

template<typename T>
class Pointer {
   ...
   template<typename U>
   Pointer(const Pointer<U> &x,
      typename boost::enable_if<
         boost::is_convertible<U*,T*>
      >::type* =0)
   : ...
   {
     ...
   }
   ...
};
```

If U* is convertible to T* the `enable_if` will have a typedef member `type` defaulting to void. Then, everything is fine. If U* is not convertible to T* this typedef member is missing, substitution fails and the constructor template is ignored.

This solves your conversion and ambiguity problems.

In response to the comment: `is_convertible` looks something like this:

```
typedef char one;         // sizeof == 1  per definition
struct two {char c[2];};  // sizeof != 1

template<typename T, typename U>
class is_convertible {
    static T source();
    static one sink(U);
    static two sink(...);
public:
    static const bool value = sizeof(sink(source()))==1;
};
```

Comment: Got the point, nice idea. The project doesn't use boost at the moment. Any idea how `is_convertible` works?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the constructor in question explicit, e.g.:

```
 template <typename t>
 explicit Pointer(const Pointer<t> &x);
```

And/or remove the `operator T *() const;` - I think this one will also create an ambiguity.

**EDIT**

Check the [std::auto_ptr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto_ptr) interface, and compare with yours. At least they solved the ambiguity.

Comment: Adding `explicilt` to the declaration has the same effect a removing it altogether: it generates a compile error (none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types...). Removing the casting operator doesn't solve the amibguity (And is a valuable part of the class anyway).

Comment: You please add the code, where Pointer is used, and please add (as comment) where a compile error occures, and which error..

Comment: Though the casting operator could still be the reason for the ambuigity (as Alexey already pointed out), its a bad idea to have implicit conversion: std::auto_ptr did not add it, and boost ptrs do not add it for the same reason (ambuigity in some cases).